# How can a MonoDevelop addin highlight a line in a text editor?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, add-in

I am working on a MonoDevelop Addin that mostly works on the source editor. Now I would like to highlight a particular line with a background color based on the line's content.

So far I see two approaches, which both do not seem to work: The first is to use the standard way MonoDevelop draws line backgrounds, which is based on errors or warnings by creating a `Task` and adding it to `TaskService.Errors` - but here I don't have the ability to define a custom color, and I only want to give a visual indication, not indicate a problem.

The second is based on the answer to [Mono.TextEditor highlight line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660859/mono-texteditor-highlight-line), which gives some valuable hints, but requires that I have an instance of `Mono.TextEditor` at hand. I already use `MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Workbench.ActiveDocument`, but this is an instance of `MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document`, and I don't see how to get a `Mono.TextEditor.TextDocument` from it.

Does anyone see a way to achieve this without defining a custom editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not say how you are getting the MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document so I am going to guess that you are doing something similar to:

```
MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document doc = MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Workbench.ActiveDocument;
```

You can get access to the TextEditor and the TextEditorDocument using similar code:

```
var view = MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Workbench.ActiveDocument.Window.ActiveViewContent as MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView;
var textEditor = view.TextEditor;
var textEditorDoc = view.Document;
```

You would need to reference the MonoDevelop.SourceEditor addin to be able to use the SourceEditorView.

Comment: Thanks! I can now get the TextEditor and add a Marker, but neither the LineBackgroundMarker nor the StyleTextMarker seem to have any effect after calling `textEditor.Document.AddMarker(lineNumber, marker);` and `textEditor.QueueDraw();` Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me. I did not call QueueDraw but just added the line background marker.

Comment: Never mind - I screw up the color definition using int values, so it always showed white background... Your solution works perfectly, even without the QueueDraw.